# How to update the dataframe row comparing data from another dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

```
df1
    antecedent  consequent  p
0   [5] [1] 1.0
1   [3] [1, 5, 4,]  1.0

    nodealarm   count1  nodealarmrank1
0   test1   110 1
1   test2   201 2
2   test3   300 3
3   test4   600 4
4   test100 60  5
```

output

```
df1
    antecedent  consequent  p
0   [test100]   [test1]  1.0
1   [test3]   [test1,test100,test4] 1.0
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please ensure that you format your question correctly. In this case it looks like there's insufficient information to answer your question even with correct formatting. Please see how to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please [`upvote and accept`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if the solution provided your required result.

Answer (score 0):

Creating dictionary [`d`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) and [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) on columns:

```
d =dict(df2[['nodealarmrank1','nodealarm']].values)

df1['antecedent'] = df1['antecedent'].apply(lambda x: list(map(d.get,x)))
df1['consequent'] = df1['consequent'].apply(lambda x: list(map(d.get,x)))

df1
    antecedent  consequent              p
0   [test100]   [test1]                 1
1   [test3]     [test1, test100, test4] 1
```

Or using for loop and [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
for column in ['antecedent','consequent']:
    df1.update(df1[column].apply(lambda x: list(map(d.get,x))))

for column in ['antecedent','consequent']:
    df1[column] = df1[column].apply(lambda x: list(map(d.get,x)))
```

Setup
dataframe 1:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'antecedent':[[5],[3]],'consequent':[[1],[1, 5, 4,]],'p':[1,1]})
df1

    antecedent  consequent  p
0   [5]         [1]         1
1   [3]         [1, 5, 4]   1
```

dataframe 2:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'nodealarm':['test1','test2','test3','test4','test100'],'count1':[110,201,300,600,60],'nodealarmrank1':[1,2,3,4,5]})
df2

    nodealarm   count1  nodealarmrank1
0   test1       110     1
1   test2       201     2
2   test3       300     3
3   test4       600     4
4   test100     60      5
```